# c3 chart shows data when I want it to hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, c3.js

I'm currently using c3 chart and what I would like to do is hide some data by default and then allow the user to view it they needed.  (Perfect scenario would be to toggle the series one at a time only). But the main issue is I can't seem to have the chart render correctly with just one series.  Here is an example. Any ideas why it showing a little of the other series? It should only show "c" (the green one)

```
var somethingWeLoadedFromTheServer = [
    {a:23, b:45, c:12},
    {a:34, b:19, c:38},
    {a:25, b:62, c:56},
    {a:44, b:88, c:74}
];

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        json: somethingWeLoadedFromTheServer,
        keys: {
            value: ['a', 'b','c'],
            //x: 'c'
        },
        type: 'bar',
        hide: ['a','b']
    },

    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
        }
    },
    axis: {
    //rotated: true
    }
//    axis: {
//      y: {
//          tick: {
//              count: 3,
//              format: d3.format('.2f')
//          }
//      }
//  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbej86Lf/

Answer (score 0):

Yeh, the json based bar charts can be a little buggy - I've actually used the effect you're seeing to help support 'non-stacked' stacked bar charts i.e. overlaying charts at the same place

This works though, hide the relevant series in the first onrendered call back - first being indicated by a flag. It should be possible to use oninit instead but doing that makes the bars 1px wide for some reason, grr (I see you filed a c3 bug, I'll add my findings onto that)

```
var firstRun = true;
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    json: somethingWeLoadedFromTheServer,
    keys: {
        value: ['a', 'b','c'],
        //x: 'c'
    },
    type: 'bar',
    //hide: ['a','b']
},

bar: {
    width: {
        ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
    }
},
axis: {
//rotated: true
},
onrendered: function () {
   if (firstRun) {
      this.api.hide(['a', 'b']);
      firstRun = false;
    }
},
//    axis: {
//      y: {
//          tick: {
//              count: 3,
//              format: d3.format('.2f')
//          }
//      }
//  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbej86Lf/1/